# System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) is not reading Current Application Folder Path

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

During Debugging my Xamarin.Forms project, **documentsPath** refers to other project folder rather than current.When checked with Android Device Monitor the database is also getting created in **data\data\otherpackage\files** rather than 
**data\data\currentpackage\files**.Never experienced this before working with SQLite ever.How to I make database get created in same application folder ?

```
 public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
            {
                var fileName = "CommonDb_1.4.db";
                var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
 var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);

           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `@PackageName` (the name of your Android Package) is set to `otherPackage`

Comment: Thanks @Ashwin Nair.That worked after I updated Manifest File.